# ng-model not scope data with ctrl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

I need to send form with post method to url. All ng-select field work, but only one input field not. Here is code. I add ctrl to ui-state like all other ctrl.

```
>  https://plnkr.co/edit/th0ueFEgrfV3TlDb115s?p=preview
```

Can someone take a look?

Comment: need  to put code proper way so easy to find bug . currently your code showing everything fine

Comment: sry for mess in code. I can't find any bug... :(

Comment: Spelling corrected.